# Redirect to route in laravel not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am working on **Laravel 5.4.36** application where my route **label** is defined in web.php as,

```
Route::get('/label/', 'LabelController@index');
```

but when I am trying to redirect from a control function to a route **label** using,

```
return redirect()->route('label');
```

> Error: InvalidArgumentException Route [label] not defined.

or

```
return Redirect::to('label');
```

> Error: FatalErrorException Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Redirect' not
>   found.

both are not not working, Can anyone help me how to redirect to a route in Laravel?

Comment: change your route like this `Route::get('/label', 'LabelController@index')->name('label');`

Comment: @rkj There is error `(1/1) FatalErrorException
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Route' not found

in LabelController.php (line 83)`

Comment: use `return redirect()->route('label');` now

Comment: you must have `Route` somewhere in your `LabelController` around `line 83`. check there or you can add `LabelController` in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`route()` redirects to a named route, so you need to name your route in your `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::name('label')->get('/label/', 'LabelController@index');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing

Comment: There is errpr, `(1/1) FatalErrorException
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Route' not found

in LabelController.php (line 84)`

Comment: You write that in your `routes/web.php` where you define your routes. Not in your controller. In your action you should use `return \Redirect::route('label');` or something

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite route to `Route::get('label', 'LabelController@index');` and then call `return redirect()->route('label');`

OR

rewrite redirection call to `return redirect()->route('/label/');`

Please try this

Answer (score 0):

In your routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/label/', 'LabelController@index')->name('label');
```

In your LabelController, at the end of your function index:

```
return redirect()->route('label');
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are many ways to do it but i prefer below two ways for redirect.

1) With out defining name of the route:

```
Route::get('/label', 'LabelController@index');
return redirect('/label');
```

2) by Defining the name of the route:

```
 Route::get('/label', 'LabelController@index')->name('label');
 return redirect()->route('label');
```

Answer (score 0):

use

> Route::get('/label', 'LabelController@index')->name('label');

instead of

> Route::get('/label/', 'LabelController@index');

remove / after label. no need of / at the end of route if you are not passing any parameters